# I applied for a visa for Canada then I lost my passport and got a new one. Is there any problem with that?

Tags: visas, passports, canada

In my medical certificate I registered with passport details and applied for a visa for Canada. A week later I lost my passport, then applied for a new one. Now I have a new passport number different from the old one. Is there a problem with this? How should I move further?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate, since the OP does not have the old passport):  [Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport)

Comment: Did you lose your passport before your visa was granted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't already get the visa before losing your passport, you should call or write to the office at which you applied for the visa and ask them what to do.