# Can I use a Canada visa in a cancelled passport?

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I have an e-Visa for Canada in a passport that was damaged. I applied for and received a new passport. Can I still use the approved visa for Canada, or do I have to apply for a new one?

Comment: Yes what will I do

Comment: Related:  [Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport)  I would expect that the usability of the visa would depend on how badly the old passport was damaged.

Comment: If the passport data page, and the visa, are both undamaged, you ought to be OK.