# Canadian visitor visa validity with passport expiring in 14 months

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I have an Indian passport that expires in 14 months. If I apply for a multiple-entry Canadian visitor visa, would I be granted a visa for just the 14 months as opposed to 10 years?

And once I renew my passport, would I have to reapply for a new visa ?

Comment: Mostly duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canada won’t give you a visa with an expiration date that exceeds that of the passport it’s in. So you’ll only get a 14month visa.

Whether it’s more affordable for you to get a new passport before you get the visa, or a new visa before you get the new passport is up to you.