# travelling to Canada on expired visa on expired passport

Tags: visas, passports, canada, visa-renewals

I received the multiple entry visa from Canadian embassy. Unfortunately they put the visa expiration date equal to 
passport expiration date. Since then my passport has expired. I have received a new passport which now has a new passport number. 
In this situation do you guys think I can travel to Canada if I take both the passports?
I guess I am confused since my visa has expired, and the link below says that you can travel to Canada if you have a valid visa on an expired passport.

[Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport?newreg=9d46a025edbb415a9c2220bef8d1e8bc)

Answer (score 2):

You need a *valid* visa to travel to Canada. It cannot be expired.

Several years ago Canada did issue visas which could have expiration dates after the expiration of the passport, but they have not done this in some time. All recent visas expire at the same time as the passport. So, when you renew your passport you must also apply for a new visa for Canada.

Comment: So I guess in the link I attach, people are talking about a visa which has no expiration date. My question here is what is the definition of valid visa?

Comment: Where do you see anything about a visa with no expiration date? I could not find that.

Comment: So my question is if my canadian visa says that expiration is Oct/14/2018, does that mean my visa is valid?

Comment: No, 14 October 2018 was a month ago.