# transfer visa to new passport

Tags: visas, canada

I have a kid and her passport is valid for another year. we registered our request to receive a visa for Canada. we used her old passport.
but I want to apply for a new passport for her, so we do not have to come back to our country. can I transfer her visa to her new passport?

Comment: What is your nationality, and what visas do you have?

Comment: @ReddHerring It doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport)

Comment: I'm not happy with the suggested duplicate Q&A. It appears to cover only the old Canadian visas, not the current ones which have expiry dates synchronized to the passport expiry date. As David Richerby explains in his answer, the OP needs to renew the passport first, before applying for the visa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never transfer visas, and you should never tamper with the sticker in your passport.
There are two possibilities for what happens in this situation: either the visa remains valid and you must bring your current passport and also the old passport that contains the visa when you travel; or the visa becomes invalid and you must apply for a new one visa when you get a new passport.

In the case of Canda, the visa remains valid and you need to bring both passports. However, Canadian policy is not to issue visas that last longer than the passport they go in (see Section 13.18 of the Immigration Canada [Port of Entry Examinations](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/resources/manuals/enf/enf04-eng.pdf) manual) so, in this case, your daughter will receive a visa that expires when her passport does. If you want a longer-term visa, you will need to renew the passport first.

Comment: +1. Just for the sake of completeness, Sometimes there are third options. UK allows you to file an application to transfer your old visa onto your new passport for a fee even though it stays valid as stated in your answer.

Comment: @David Richerby. we registered for a new passport but it was not ready to untile we applied for the visa (it is not ready yet). the old passport is valid for another year so it won't expire and the visa will be valid too. but I worried that when new passport arrives we encounter problem entering Canada. I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: @user97397 as long as you have a valid passport and a valid Canadian visa (in that passport or another one), you’re good to go, as far as I can see.